# postgresql - 'Group' similar queries as subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

At this moment I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    sync_id integer NOT NULL,
    color VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE syncs 
(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    some_column_name VARCHAR (100)
);
```

and 3 similar queries:

```
SELECT
  sc.id,
  COALESCE(t1.sync_id, 0::bigint) as t1_count_red
FROM syncs sc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(t.id), t.sync_id as sync_id
  FROM table_1 t
  WHERE t.color = 'red'
  GROUP BY sync_id
) t1 ON t1.sync_id = sc.id;


SELECT
  sc.id,
  COALESCE(t1.sync_id, 0::bigint) as t1_count_green
FROM syncs sc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(t.id), t.sync_id as sync_id
  FROM table_1 t
  WHERE t.color = 'green'
  GROUP BY sync_id
) t1 ON t1.sync_id = sc.id;

SELECT
  sc.id,
  COALESCE(t1.sync_id, 0::bigint) as t1_total_count
FROM syncs sc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT count(t.id), t.sync_id as sync_id
  FROM table_1 t
  GROUP BY sync_id
) t1 ON t1.sync_id = sc.id;
```

As we can see, this queries are very similar - the main difference is in `WHERE` condition and last query's is without it but now I have 3 separated queries. Is it possible to get below result?

I have already tried to group it by subqueries but I was get error "subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| sync_id | count_red | count_green | total_count |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|   ...   |    ...    |     ...     |     ...     |
+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b297c/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres is best done with the `FILTER` construct:

```
SELECT sc.id, t.count_red, t.count_green, t.count_total
FROM syncs sc LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t.sync_id as sync_id,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t.color = 'red') as count_red,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t.color = 'green') as count_green,
             COUNT(*) as count_total
      FROM table_1 t  
      GROUP BY sync_id
     ) t
     ON t.sync_id = sc.id;
```